# Darf ich sagen "geistiges Bankett"?

Tags: english-to-german, phrase

Ich arbeite gerade an meinem Motivationsschreiben, und ich wollte "intellectual banquette" schreiben. Ich weiss aber nicht, ob "Bankett" die richtige Übersetzung ist?

Der originale Satz ist:

> Meine letzten eineinhalb Jahre an der Universität XX waren ein totales
> intellektuelle Bankett:......

Als ich "intellectual banquette" schreibe, denke ich eine figurative Verwendung der "banquet" von einer Prose, die von A.Rimbaud ist und lautet

> Once, if my memory serves me well, my life was a banquet where every
> heart revealed itself, where every wine flowed.

(es ist ursprünglich Französisch, leider kann ich nicht ins deutsch übersetzen).

Deshalb wollte ich mit "intellectual banquet" beschreiben, dass ich eines intensive intellektuelle und kontemplative Leben erfahren habe. Dieses Leben wird als ein "banquet" betrachtet, weil ich möchte betonen, wie vielfältig und attraktiv die (philosophische) Gedanken die ich gelernt habe, sind und wie beschäftigt ich bin.

Comment: Can you explain what a *intellectual banquette* is? Otherwise the question could be closed as *needs more details or clarity* or as *requires expertise of another language*.

Comment: In meinen Augen ist *intellektuelles Bankett* eine sehr schöne Formulierung und ich wüsste nicht, was daran missverständlich sein könnte.

Comment: @Olafant Finde ich auch. Ob jede(r) Arbeitgeber(in) das so findet...?

Comment: @c.p. Vermutlich nicht jeder. Manche Arbeitgeber sollte man aber auch von vornherein meiden.

Comment: Ich habe Bankett in dem Zusammenhang noch nie gehört. "geistig" bei einem Bankett (oder auch einem geisteswissenschaftlichen Studium ;-)) könnet sich auf alkoholische Getränke beziehen, da ist wohl ein Schmunzeln zu erwarten. Mein Vorschlag wäre Analogien und Metaphern zu vermeiden und direkter zu beschrieben worauf man hinaus will.

Answer (score 1):

Das französische Wort *»banquette«* bezeichnet eine Sitzbank auf der man auch schlafen kann, eine Klavierbank (die kleine Bank auf der Klavierspieler sitzen), im Sport die Bank auf der die Ersatzspieler sitzen und eine Fensterbank. Eine weitere Bedeutung ist: Schotterweg. Insbesondere dann, wenn dieser Schotterweg der Rand einer asphaltierten Straße ist.

Im Deutschen gibt es das Wort *»Bankett«* zweimal. Einmal kam es aus der italienischen Sprache zu uns, aber eigentlich doch aus dem Deutschen. Das ging so:

Das deutsch Wort *»Bank«* (Bedeutung: *Sitzbank*) wurde von den Italienern importiert und zu *»banco«* (Bedeutung: Sitzbank, Werkbank, Theke. Aus der Bedeutung *Theke* entstand in Italien dann auch die Bedeutung *Geldinstitut,* weil die ersten Banker nur eine Theke als Arbeitsplatz brauchten). In der Bedeutung *Geldinstitut* wurde es dann wieder als *Bank* zurück in die deutsche Sprache importiert. Aber auch die Verkleinerungsform *»banchetto«* (wörtlich: *»Bänkchen«*, in Österreich *»Bankerl«*) wurde in die deutsche Sprache als *»Bankett«* aufgenommen, aber mit einer ganz anderen Bedeutung. Das aus dem Italienischen importierte Wort *»Bankett«* bedeutet:

- eine luxuriöse gesellschaftliche Feier, bei der feine Spesen gereicht werden. Oftmals im Zusammenhang mit einer offiziellen und/oder diplomatischen Zusammenkunft. (Beispielsweise wenn der Bundespräsident Staatsgäste empfängt.)
- Der Bereich eines luxuriösen Hotels, in dem eine solche Feier veranstaltet wird.

Aber auch das eingangs beschriebene französische Wort *»banquette«* drang als Fremdwort in die deutsche Sprache, wurde ebenfalls zu *»Bankett«,* wird aber nur im Straßenbau verwendet:

- Der Schotterstreifen neben einer asphaltierten Straße.

---

Ich habe keine Ahnung, was der Ausdruck *»intellectual banquette«* bedeuten soll, und aus welcher Sprache er überhaupt stammt. (Sowohl *»intellectual«* als auch *»banquette«* kommen in vielen Sprachen in genau dieser Schreibweise vor.) Wenn du damit eine festliche Feier bezeichnen willst, an der hautsächlich Intellektuelle teilnehmen, kann man im Deutschen durchaus von einem *intellektuellen Bankett* sprechen:

> Der Präsident der Gesellschaft zur Förderung der Hochkultur lud einige Nobelpreisträger zum **intellektuellen Bankett** ins Grandhotel.

Das darf man schreiben, und es wird auch richtig verstanden werden.

Man könnte aber aus der Bedeutung *»Straßenrand«* auch eine übertragene Bedeutung ableiten, und dann mit dem *intellektuellen Bankett* eher bildungferne Gesellschaftsschichten meinen:

> QAnon-Anhänger, Coronaleugner, und Anhänger der Flat-Earth-Bewegung bildeten das **intellektuelle Bankett** im Reigen jener, die vergangenen Samstag auf die Straße gingen um gegen die Corona-Maßnahmen zu demonstrieren.

Das darf man selbstverständlich auch schreiben. Weil das Wort *»Bankett«* aber selten in dieser übertragenen Bedeutung verwendet wird, ist zu befürchten, dass ein kleiner Teil der Leser es nicht auf Anhieb verstehen wird.

Allerdings sehe ich nicht, wie man eine der beiden Bedeutung sinnvoll in ein Motivationsschreiben einbringen könnte.

Comment: @Mr.Wohoo: Wenn eine Frage auf Deutsch gestellt wird, sollten nicht nur alle Antworten auf Deutsch erfolgen, sondern auch alle Kommentare. Es gibt keinen Grund anzunehmen, dass ein Besucher eines Deutsch-Forums die englische Sprache beherrscht. Was hier https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/830/1487 über Antworten gesagt wird, gilt auch für Kommentare.

Comment: Entschuldigung. Sie haben Recht. Ich habe den alte Kommentar gelöscht.

Comment: Gemeint ist ursprünglich natürlich ein "Festmahl mit Gehirnfutter"

Comment: Der letzte Satz ist eigentlich der wichtigste Punkt.

Answer (score 1):

Originaltext:

> Jadis, si je me souviens bien, ma vie etait un festin ou s'ouvraient tous les cœurs, ou tous les vins coulaient.

Also ist ein *Festmahl* (festin) oder *Festessen* gemeint. *Bankett* kann man dazu auch sagen.

Mit sowas wie "intellektuelles Festmahl" liegst du wahrscheinlich nicht schlecht.

Answer (score 1):

"Intellektuelles Bankett" würde der Leser zwar verstehen, aber es besteht die Gefahr, dass er den Verfasser als verschroben ansähe.

Hier einige Vorschläge:

Meine letzten eineinhalb Jahre an der Universität XX waren

- ein intellektuelles Highlight für mich.
- eine besondere intellektuelle Stimulation.
- intellektuell besonders anregend.

Comment: +1 für ersten Satz. Allerdings würde ich als Arbeitgeber bzw. Personalabteilung spätestens nach *Highlight* nicht mehr lesen wollen. Vielleicht nicht so passend in dem Kontext.

Answer (score 0):

Die Bedeutung von *geistiges Bankett* ist zumindest schwammig, da mir das Wort *Bankett* zu konkret und zu stark mit dem Aspekt Essen verbunden zu sein scheint. Unter einem geistigen Bankett würde ich mir ein imaginäres Abendessen vorstellen. *Intellektuelles Bankett* stünde dagegen eher für ein tatsächliches Bankett von Intellektuellen. In beiden Fällen kommt die übertragene Bedeutung nicht wirklich hinüber. Höchstens *Bankett für den Geist* wäre eindeutiger.

Daher würde ich [*Symposion*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symposion) als Alternative vorschlagen, da es zwar ursprünglich auch *Fest-* oder *Gastmahl* bedeutet, aber durch [Platons *Symposion*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symposion_(Platon)) und die heutige Verwendung des Begriffs *Symposium* für wissenschaftliche Tagungen der *intellektuelle* Aspekt im Vordergrund steht. Ein Beispiel:

> Das Studium XY war für mich…
>
> - ein intellektuelles/geistiges Symposion/Symposium.
> - ein Symposion/Symposium für meinen Geist.